# how to add elements of a list into another list with no bracket and no imports in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, append, tuples

Im trying to put specific number of elements of a list in a list like:

```
L = [1,2,3,4]
```

and say I want point 1 - 3 to get put back in to the list giving me:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4]
```

but i keep getting:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,[2,3,4]]
```

how do i get the second result  with out importing anything or defining a new function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add lists together and slice them:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4]
>>> L+L[1:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

So if you want to update `L` with the last three elements:

```
L = L+L[1:4]
print L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks so much this is helping a lot now what im trying to do is make it so that i can aadd on to the list from a given point to the end of the list where the end of the list is n. I tried using something like L+L[2:-1] but that doesnt work.

Comment: Hmm, I think you were close. If you want to get all of the elements starting after the second, up to the end, for instance you would do `L[2:]`. When you do `L[2:-1]` you are leaving out the last element. So, if you want all elements starting after `i`, for instance, you can do `L[i:]`. If you want to include `i` in your slice, you will need `L[i-1:]`, because you want to start slicing one item before `i` in that case. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you want to `extend` your list instead of `append`ing a single item to it. You haven't shown your code, so I don't know exactly how you're going about getting the values `2, 3, 4`, but I'd generally do something like `L.extend(L[1:4])`. This modifies the `L` list in place. If you want to make a new list with the longer sequence of values, use `+` as described in [rofls's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162993/1405065).